# Docker node alpine node-sass Module build failed even ran `npm rebuild node-sass`

Tags: node.js, docker, webpack, node-sass

I am using Docker node-alpine for my project.

my project structure is like this

```
Project
  /client (for front end client where is need node-sass)
    package.json
    webpack.js
  index.js
  package.json
```

This is my dockerfile

```
FROM node:8.16.0-alpine

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

# --no-cache: download package index on-the-fly, no need to cleanup afterwards
# --virtual: bundle packages, remove whole bundle at once, when done
RUN apk --no-cache --virtual build-dependencies add \
    python \
    make \
    g++ \
    bash

RUN npm install -g nodemon

COPY package.json package.json
COPY client/package.json client/package.json

RUN npm install
RUN npm run install:client
RUN cd client && npm rebuild node-sass --force
# RUN npm run sass:rebuild:client

COPY . .

LABEL maintainer="Varis Darasirikul"

VOLUME ["/app/public"]

CMD npm run dev
```

This is `webpack` rules in my client

```
{
        test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            options: {
              hmr: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
              // if hmr does not work, this is a forceful method.
              reloadAll: true,
            },
          },
          'css-loader',
          'postcss-loader',
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
```

But after i try to run `webpack-dev-server` inside `client` folder.
I got this error.

```
Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Linux/musl 64-bit with Node.js 8.x
Run `npm rebuild node-sass` to download the binding for your current environment.
```

Which i already did inside my `dockerfile`.

So how can i fix this, anything that i miss inside my docker file?

Thanks!

Comment: Just don’t use alpine image for node & sass. It was pain in the a**. Switch to Jessie-slim Ora’s stretch-slim instead.

Comment: Did you ever fix this? I am using `FROM node:12` and `FROM node:12.5.0` which I run the command in the Dockerfile `npm rebuild node-sass` and it does not fix the issue?

Comment: @wuno i already fix that by using this method
https://github.com/manjarb/FullStackEngineerChallenge/blob/master/docker-compose.yml